# Game doesn't work, but my code looks fine

Tags: javascript

I've been following an online tutorial for making a [Breakout Game](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript) using JS, but it doesn't work. Even something as simple as an alert popup doesn't work. All of this started happening after I created the keyboard controls, and all of the errors are in that section as well. But it looks fine, i've compared the sample code with mine and everything's identical. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gamedev</title>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            background:rgba(104, 10, 93, 0.61);
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
</body>

<script>
    // JS goes here
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var ballRadius = 10;
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleWidth = 75;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
    var rightPressed = false;
    var leftPressed = false;

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUphandler, false);

    alert('test')

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
            rightPressed = true;
        }
        elseif(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
            leftPressed = true;
        }
    }

    function keyUpHandler(e) {
        if(e.key -- "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
            rightPressed = false;
        }
        elseif(e.key-- "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
            leftPressed = false;
        }
    }

    function drawBall() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#EE82EE";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    function drawPaddle() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleheight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#9400D3";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawPaddle();

        if(x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
            dy = -dy;
        }

        if(rightPressed) {
            paddleX += 7;
            if (paddleX + paddleWidth > canvas.width){
                paddleX = canvas.width - paddleWidth;
            }
        }
        else if(leftPressed) {
            paddleX -= 7;
            if (paddleX < 0){
                paddleX = 0;
            }
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }
    }
        setInterval(draw, 10);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if(e.key -- "Right"` doesn't look quite right.

Comment: Your html has a problem. You close the body tag twice.

Comment: In the future, if you know roughly what you added that made things stop working, you can try deleting half the code at a time until it works. That will help you narrow down the problem further.

Comment: I've changed those, now down to two errors: expected ; at [50, 57] and [59, 57]

Comment: Nice work, good luck!

Comment: You have many syntax errors in your JavaScript that you should be able to detect with a modern IDE (like VS Code). For example, there is no such thing as "elseif", it should be "else if" with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have numerous typos in your code. This version should work better (at least it does not generate any errors):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gamedev</title>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            background:rgba(104, 10, 93, 0.61);
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

</body>

<script>
    // JS goes here
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var ballRadius = 10;
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleWidth = 75;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
    var rightPressed = false;
    var leftPressed = false;

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

    alert('test')

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
            rightPressed = true;
        }
        else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
            leftPressed = true;
        }
    }

    function keyUpHandler(e) {
        if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
            rightPressed = false;
        }
        else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
            leftPressed = false;
        }
    }

    function drawBall() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#EE82EE";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    function drawPaddle() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#9400D3";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawPaddle();

        if(x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
            dy = -dy;
        }

        if (rightPressed) {
            paddleX += 7;
            if (paddleX + paddleWidth > canvas.width){
                paddleX = canvas.width - paddleWidth;
            }
        }
        else if(leftPressed) {
            paddleX -= 7;
            if (paddleX < 0){
                paddleX = 0;
            }
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }
    }
        setInterval(draw, 10);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: OP should use winMerge or similar tool for compare and keep learning.